# Mapping into a geometric realization.

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories

Suppose $S$ is a simplicial set, $X$ is a space, and we are given a map
`\[
f: \text{Sing}\,X\to S.
\]`
When is is possible to produce a map $X\to |S|$?

We can take the realization of $f$, to get $|f|:|\text{Sing}\;X|\to |S|$, and then 
the question becomes: when does $|f|$ factor through the counit map $|\text{Sing}\;X|\to X$ (at least up to homotopy)?

It does if $X$ is a CW-complex, which is not the case for my example.  What about if $S$ is a Kan complex?  Does that help, or are the properties of $X$ really the key here?

Comment: In the case when $f$ is the identity map, you are sort of hoping for $|f|$ to be a homotopy equivalence, or at least to have a left homotopy inverse. Unlikely if $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. (And note that $|Sing/ X$ is always a Kan complex.)

Comment: Yeah that is more or less what I expected.  Thanks, Tom.